# Needed Download Speed

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

First of all, sorry for my English.
I need some kind of assistance with Forge. I need to display the download speed of the BIM model on the Unity.UI, be it the .RVT or whatever is downloaded from BIM360. Is it possible to know where it is downloading exactly to be able to put a count of downloaded bytes there?.
Another question. Currently the download time from Autodesk servers is approximately 110 seconds.
We understand that the download is by meshes packages. Is there a way to speed up this download? Our client needs this download to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The size (in Mb) depends of the model, so it hard to tell you how large a RVT image could be. It also depends on the asset quality, and what you actually requesting to view. So I am afraid I cannot really answer that question. However, if you are interested to create a progress bar in your UI, you can ask the number of triangles, material definitions, and textures from the model manifest, and calculate the % download from there, depending which technology you are using to access the data. There is an example in the AR|VR toolkit doing this, but again it depends of the technology you are using.

Assuming you are using the AR|VR Toolkit, mesh request are done in parallel, so the speed to download and instantiate meshes depends of your internet bandwidth, and speed of you device to run Unity. In the toolkit, you may accelerate the download, but accept to lose control of the UI during that period. It is a compromise to make due to the Unity limitation running singe threaded.

The toolkit can also convert models to glTF, and you could using the gltfast Unity plugin to get better performances, but lose metadata associated to objects. Another compromise due to the nature of glTF at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. We know that the download time depends on what we need and what we bring from the BIM360 server. What percentage of savings could we have using the methods you have proposed? 5%? 10%?
In case we see that the savings percentage is considerable, what would we have to modify so that the process is like the one you have indicated? We use the Script ForgeLoader.cs to load the models and metadata.

Comment: You probably using an old version of the Unity Forge Toolkit. I got a more recent one, running faster, and using the latest Unity API. However, I haven't published it yet. If you interested to get the work in progress, please contact me directly at cyrille @ autodesk.com.